# Accessing another maibox in outlook using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I have two mailboxes in my Outlook.

One that is mine and it automatically logs me in when I log in to my pc and another I have that is for mail bounces.

I really need to access the inbox of the mail's account but I just can't seem to do it.

And there is no way I can make the mailbox of the mail account to be my default mailbox

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Public Sub GetMails()

    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim aFolder As Outlook.Folders

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set myRecipient = ns.CreateRecipient("mail@mail.pt")
    myRecipient.Resolve
    If myRecipient.Resolved Then
        MsgBox ("Resolved")
        Set aFolder = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderInbox)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Failed")
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem I am getting is at the

`Set aFolder = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderInbox)`

I get the Resolved msgbox so I know that is working but after that I get an error:

> Run-Time Error

which doesn't say much about the error itself.

Can anyone help me out here please? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the folder you wish to access is not an Exchange folder, you will need to find it, if it is an Exchange folder, try logging on to the namespace.

**Log on to NameSpace**

```
  Set oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  oNS.Logon
```

**Find Folder**
As far as I recall, this code is from Sue Mosher.

```
Public Function GetFolder(strFolderPath As String) As Object 'MAPIFolder
' strFolderPath needs to be something like
'   "Public Folders\All Public Folders\Company\Sales" or
'   "Personal Folders\Inbox\My Folder" ''

Dim apOL As Object 'Outlook.Application '
Dim objNS As Object 'Outlook.NameSpace '
Dim colFolders As Object 'Outlook.Folders '
Dim objFolder As Object 'Outlook.MAPIFolder '
Dim arrFolders() As String
Dim I As Long

On Error GoTo TrapError

    strFolderPath = Replace(strFolderPath, "/", "\") 
    arrFolders() = Split(strFolderPath, "\")

    Set apOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNS = apOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")


    On Error Resume Next

    Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.Item(arrFolders(0))

    If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
        For I = 1 To UBound(arrFolders)
            Set colFolders = objFolder.Folders
            Set objFolder = Nothing
            Set objFolder = colFolders.Item(arrFolders(I))

            If objFolder Is Nothing Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Set GetFolder = objFolder
    Set colFolders = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set apOL = Nothing


End Function
```

Comment: wow! Thanks for the code. I managed to resolve my problem by creating a new profile and specifying only the account that I wanted, so the code runs on that account :) Thanks